# How to get topic name while using spark-streaming-mqtt-assembly in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, mqtt

I am using spark-streaming-mqtt-assembly package and MQTTUtils class in pyspark to connect to MQTT broker using command:

```
mqttStream = MQTTUtils.createStream(ssc, brokerUrl, topic)
```

I have subscribed to a wildcard topic and I am interested in finding out an exact topic name for each received payload being stored in mqttStream. mqttStream is of type DStream.

Paho-mqtt-client provides similar funcitonality with msg.topic:

```
def on_message(self, mqttc, obj, msg):
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.qos)+" "+str(msg.payload))
```

Can we achieve something similar using spark-streaming-mqtt-assembly in pyspark? Any pointers will be helpful.